# LOESS works in ggplot2 but function does not work on its own

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I create a figure in `ggplot2` and fit a loess model to the data using `stat_smooth(method = 'loess')` there is no problem. However, when I use the same data to fit a loess model using the `loess()` function, I get error messages. Why does loess work in `ggplot2` but not in the `loess()` function? How can I get the `loess()` function to work with my data?

Example Data

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 15))
colnames(df)[1:2] <- c("date", "fraction")
df$date <- c("2020-07-15", "2020-08-17", "2020-09-16", "2020-10-14", "2021-05-25",
             "2021-06-23", "2021-07-21", "2021-08-19", "2021-09-20", "2021-10-20",
             "2022-04-20", "2022-05-17", "2022-06-13", "2022-07-13", "2022-08-10")
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df$fraction <- c(7.0,  1.1,  0.0,  4.9, 41.0, 50.7, 53.4,
                 51.2, 37.0, 54.4, 60.4, 75.0, 98.8, 92.1, 97.0)
df
```

`ggplot2` figure showing loess works with the example data

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = fraction)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "loess")
```

`loess()` function not working with the example data. How can I get the `loess()` function to work with the example data? Ultimately what I am after is the r-squared value of the loess model fit in the above figure.

```
aa <- loess(fraction~date, data = df)
```

Comment: Make sure to convert the date to a numeric value: `loess(fraction~as.numeric(date), data = df)`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert the `Date` format to a `numeric` format

```r
aa <- loess(fraction ~ as.numeric(date), data = df)
```